# Does Arara have variables?

Tags: arara

Does Arara scripts have variables that can be used to communicate state from one line to another down the road? For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this.

```
% arara: isBibChanged = changed('bib')
% arara: pdflatex if isBibChanged
% arara: biber if isBibChanged
```

Just to clarify: this script is just an example for illustration purposes. I'm not interested in this script per se. I'm interested in the general question presented above.